# Rename files using cmd ren command

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

I'm a newbie at this but have spent the afternoon searching your forums. While there are several posts about the ren command i can't seem to get mine to work?!

I would like to change:

```
A22-7000
A22-7001
A22-7003
```

to:

```
A24-7000
A24-7001
A22-7003
```

I opened the cmd window in the folder location and tried various forms of the following:

```
ren *A22 *A24
```

I know this should be easy but it's been driving me insane! Also, if anyone has a link to good tutorials where I can learn this sort of this that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to change from `A22-7003` to `A22-7002`?

Comment: Do the to numbers have to be consecutive?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. It is only the A22 part I wanted to change.

Comment: So it should be `A24-7003` instead of `A22-7003` in the "to" list? In other words replace all `A22` by `A24`?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Someone below got it spot on, just move the * to the other side of the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got the concept of wildcards wrong.

`*A22` means "anything that ends with A22"

`*` means "any count of characters"

`?` means "one character"

What you want is probably:

```
ren A22* A24*
```

`A22*` means "anything that starts with `A22` followed by any number of chars"

Comment: hello stephan `ren` rename all folder or file if use wildcard you should filter file or folder for change name

Comment: ren A22* A24* Worked perfectly! Sorry for such a simple question, is there any place you might know of where I can read over basic stuff like this?

Comment: [DosTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/) would be a good starting point. And of course reading here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

first you should certain you want change folder or file name when you use just ren that rename all find with your wild card !
see my example 
if you have A22-7000 file and folder when you ren A22* A24* you change all folder and file if you want change 
just folder

```
random.bat
dir /A:D /b | findstr.exe /n /R "a*" > s:\sites\file-count.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "s:\sites\file-count.txt"') do set NUMBER-OF-FILES=%%A

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%number-of-files%) DO CALL rename.bat %%A
```

rename.bat

```
:rename

FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "s:\sites\file-count.txt" ^| 

findstr "%1:"') do ren %%B a24-%RANDOM%
```

just file :
random.bat

```
dir /A:-D /b | findstr.exe /n /R "a*" > s:\sites\file-count.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "s:\sites\file-count.txt"') do set NUMBER-OF-FILES=%%A

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%number-of-files%) DO CALL rename.bat %%A
```

rename.bat:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "s:\sites\file-count.txt" ^| 

    findstr "%1:"') do ren %%B a24-%RANDOM%
```

also you can do this with powershell script like 
just for folder

```
gci -Directory -Filter A22* | foreach { Rename-Item $_.Name -NewName A24* }
```

just for file

```
gci -file -Filter A22* | foreach { Rename-Item $_.Name -NewName A24* }
```

Comment: even without trying, I'm quite sure, none of your examples will work.

Comment: @Stephan first sorry my batch has problem i check and change now with out any problem work second i do not need you accept me i answer to question Andrew asked ! and for `ren ` command check [link](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command change file and folder name